Flatlist Scrolling issue Expo React Native
I am creating a Expo React Native Project with Firebase backend.
I want to display posts to my users so that they can vertically scroll it like Instagram reels.
So I used Flatlist from react-native . 
Problem : I am fetching the contents of the flatlist from my firebase , It consists of a video and some Ui interactive elements to show on top of the posts.
But for some reason when the user scrolls I am not able to keep a single post in the users screen.
Everytime the scroll happens, some part of the previous post from bottom is visible in the viewport of the user. And this overlapping part increases with every post.
After scrolling over 5-6 posts, 2 videos render in the users viewport simultaneously.
The current code is very non-optimised & messed up but this single issue is creating a bad experience.

Here are some essential files of my code


ScrollScreen.jsx - This is my Screen which I am rendering in my Stack navigator.
Scroller.jsx - This is my component which is inside the screen above & it is rendering that     Flatlist which is shown to the users
index.js -  Mypost component which contains the code to render the video and other UI elements of each post.

import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import Scroller from '../components/Scroller';
import { getCurrentUserKeywords, getPost } from '../redux/actions/user';

const ScrollScreen = () => {
  const { posts } = useSelector(store => store.user);
  const [change, setChange] = useState(false);
  const [filteredPosts, setFilteredPosts] = useState([]);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    (
      async function () {
        dispatch(getPost());
      }
    )()
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('change')
    setChange(prev => !prev);
  }, [posts])

  useEffect(() => {
    const filterPostsByKeywords = async () => {
      const keywords = await getCurrentUserKeywords();
      // Fetch the current user's keywords
      const filtered = posts.filter(post =>
        post.hashtags.some(hashtag => keywords.includes(hashtag))
        //  each post has a 'hashtags' array
      );
      setFilteredPosts(filtered);
      console.log(`Filtered posts length: ${filtered.length}`);
    };


    if (posts.length > 0) {
      filterPostsByKeywords();
    }
  }, [posts]);
  return (
    <View>
      <Scroller posts={filteredPosts} change={change} profile={false} />
    </View>
  )
}

export default ScrollScreen

import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { Dimensions, FlatList, StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import useMaterialNavBarHeight from '../hooks/useMaterialNavBarHeight';
import PostSingle from './post';

export default function Scroller({ posts: allPosts, change, profile, currentIndex }) {
    const [posts, setPosts] = useState(allPosts);
    const isScrollTab = useRef(true);
    const mediaRefs = useRef([]);
    const storeCellRef = useRef([]);
    const currentVideoRes = useRef(null);
    const navigation = useNavigation();

    const { change: pageChange } = useSelector(store => store.user);

    useEffect(() => {
        setPosts(allPosts);
    }, [allPosts, change]);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('mount');
    }, [pageChange]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const handleScreenChange = () => {
            if (currentVideoRes.current) currentVideoRes.current.stop();
            isScrollTab.current = false;
        };

        const handleFocus = () => {
            isScrollTab.current = true;
            if (currentVideoRes.current) currentVideoRes.current.play();
        };

        const unsubscribeBlur = navigation.addListener('blur', handleScreenChange);
        const unsubscribeFocus = navigation.addListener('focus', handleFocus);

        return () => {
            unsubscribeFocus();
            unsubscribeBlur();
        };
    }, [navigation]);

    const onViewableItemsChanged = useRef(({ changed }) => {
        changed.forEach(element => {
            const cell = mediaRefs.current[element.key];
            if (cell) {
                if (element.isViewable && isScrollTab.current) {
                    // Stop all videos
                    for (let index = 0; index < storeCellRef.current.length; index++) {
                        const cell = storeCellRef.current[index];
                        cell.stop();
                    }
                    // Clear the array
                    storeCellRef.current = [];
                    // Play the current video
                    cell.play();
                    currentVideoRes.current = cell;
                    storeCellRef.current.push(cell);
                } else {
                    cell.stop();
                    // Remove the cell from the array
                    storeCellRef.current = storeCellRef.current.filter(c => c !== cell);
                }
            }
        });
    });

    const feedItemHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height - useMaterialNavBarHeight(profile);

    const [followedUsers, setFollowedUsers] = useState(new Set());
    const renderItem = ({ item, index }) => {
        return (
            <View style={{ height: feedItemHeight, backgroundColor: 'black' }}>
                <PostSingle followedUsers={followedUsers}
                    setFollowedUsers={setFollowedUsers} item={item} key={index} ref={ref => (mediaRefs.current[item.id] = ref)} />
            </View>
        );
    };

    const handleEndReach = () => {
        setPosts(prevPosts => [...prevPosts, ...allPosts]);
    }

    return (
        <FlatList
            windowSize={4}
            data={posts}
            initialScrollIndex={currentIndex}
            getItemLayout={(data, index) => (
                { length: feedItemHeight, offset: feedItemHeight * index, index }
            )}
            renderItem={renderItem}
            initialNumToRender={1}
            maxToRenderPerBatch={2}
            removeClippedSubviews
            viewabilityConfig={{
                itemVisiblePercentThreshold: 50
            }}
            pagingEnabled
            decelerationRate={'normal'}
            onViewableItemsChanged={onViewableItemsChanged.current} /*
            to fix the audio leak bug
            */
            keyExtractor={item => item.id || String(item.index)}
            showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
            showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
            onEndReached={handleEndReach}
        />
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: { flex: 1 }
});


Dont consider all the UI from the below file , You could just consider the Video tag and its still giving the same issue
import { ResizeMode, Video } from "expo-av";
import React, {
  forwardRef,
  useEffect,
  useImperativeHandle,
  useRef,
  useState,
} from "react";
import {
  ActivityIndicator,
  FlatList,
  Image,
  Linking,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  TouchableWithoutFeedback,
  View,
} from "react-native";
// import { useUser } from '../../hooks/useUser'
// import PostSingleOverlay from './overlay'
import { Feather } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { LinearGradient } from "expo-linear-gradient";
import { Avatar } from "react-native-paper";
import index from "uuid-random";
import { COLORS } from "../../constants";
import tw from "../../customtwrnc";
import {
  LikePost,
  checkFollow,
  checkLike,
  followUser,
  getUserById,
} from "../../redux/actions/user";
import CommentModel from "./CommentModel";
import styles from "./styles";

const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
  <TouchableOpacity>
    <View style={tw`mx-1`}>
      <Text style={tw`text-sm text-[${COLORS.secondary}] font-montserrat`}>
        {item}
      </Text>
    </View>
  </TouchableOpacity>
);

export const PostSingle = forwardRef(({ item, ...props }, parentRef) => {
  const video = React.useRef(null);
  const timeoutref = React.useRef(null);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = React.useState(true);
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const [longPressTimer, setLongPressTimer] = useState(null);
  const [videoStop, setVideoStop] = useState(false);
  const [isLike, setIsLike] = useState(false);
  const [likesCount, setLikesCount] = useState(0);
  const [likeLoading, setLikeLoading] = useState(false);
  const [cursorPosition, setCursorPosition] = useState({ x: 0, y: 0 });
  const bottomSheetModalRef = useRef(null);
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const [mute, setMute] = useState(false);
  const [showPopup, setShowPopup] = useState(false);
  const [imageFailedToLoad, setImageFailedToLoad] = useState(false);
  const [isCommentModalVisible, setIsCommentModalVisible] = useState(false);

  useImperativeHandle(parentRef, () => ({
    play,
    unload,
    stop,
  }));

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      console.log("unloading");
      unload();
    };
  }, []);

  const handleLoadStart = () => {
    setIsLoading(true);
  };

  const handleReadyForDisplay = () => {
    setIsLoading(false);
  };

  const play = async () => {
    if (video.current == null) {
      return;
    }

    // if video is already playing return
    const status = await video.current.getStatusAsync();
    if (status?.isPlaying) {
      return;
    }
    try {
      await video.current.playAsync();
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("error", e.message);
    }
  };

  const stop = async () => {
    if (video.current == null) {
      return;
    }

    // if video is already stopped return
    const status = await video.current.getStatusAsync();
    if (!status?.isPlaying) {
      return;
    }
    try {
      await video.current.stopAsync();
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };

  const unload = async () => {
    if (video.current == null) {
      return;
    }

    try {
      await video.current.unloadAsync();
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };

  const handleOpen = (link) => {
    Linking.openURL(link);
  };

  const handlePressIn = () => {
    const timer = setTimeout(async () => {
      await video.current.pauseAsync();
      setVideoStop(true);
    }, 1000);
    setLongPressTimer(timer);
  };

  const handlePressOut = async () => {
    if (longPressTimer) {
      clearTimeout(longPressTimer);
    }
    await video.current.playAsync();
    setVideoStop(false);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    (async function () {
      const user = await getUserById(item.creator);
      const like = await checkLike(item.id);
      setUser(user);
      setIsLike(like);
    })();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    setLikesCount(item.likesCount);
  }, [item]);

  const HandleLike = async (id) => {
    if (likeLoading) {
      return;
    }
    setLikeLoading(true);
    if (isLike) {
      setIsLike(false);
      setLikesCount((prev) => prev - 1);
    } else {
      setIsLike(true);
      setLikesCount((prev) => prev + 1);
    }

    await LikePost(id);
    setLikeLoading(false);
  };

  const OpenComments = () => {
    console.log("opening...");
    // bottomSheetModalRef.current.open();
    setIsCommentModalVisible(!isCommentModalVisible);
  };
  const closeModal = () => {
    setIsCommentModalVisible(!isCommentModalVisible);
  };
  const handleProfile = () => {
    stop();
    navigation.navigate("profile", { uid: user.uid });
  };

  const handleMuteToggle = async () => {
    if (video.current) {
      video.current.setIsMutedAsync(!mute);
    }
    setMute((prev) => !prev);
    setShowPopup(true);
    if (timeoutref.current) {
      clearTimeout(timeoutref);
    }
    timeoutref.current = setTimeout(() => {
      setShowPopup(false);
    }, 500);
    console.log("muting...");
  };

  const handleMuteToggleLong = () => {
    setShowPopup(false);
    video.current.setIsMutedAsync(false);
  };

  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const { followedUsers, setFollowedUsers } = props;
  const isFollowing = followedUsers.has(item.creator);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async function () {
      if (user) {
        const ans = await checkFollow(user.uid);
        if (ans) {
          followedUsers.add(user.uid);
        } else {
          followedUsers.delete(user.uid);
        }
        setFollowedUsers(new Set(followedUsers));
      }
    })();
  }, [user]);

  const handleFollow = async () => {
    if (loading) {
      console.log("loading...");
      return;
    }
    setLoading(true);
    const isCurrentlyFollowing = followedUsers.has(user.uid);
    await followUser(user.uid, isCurrentlyFollowing);
    if (isCurrentlyFollowing) {
      followedUsers.delete(user.uid);
    } else {
      followedUsers.add(user.uid);
    }
    setFollowedUsers(new Set(followedUsers));
    setLoading(false);
  };

  function isValidUrl(string) {
    try {
      new URL(string);
      return true;
    } catch (_) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
      {isLoading && (
        <View
          style={{
            justifyContent: "center",
            alignItems: "center",
            backgroundColor: COLORS.primary,
            zIndex: 10,
            position: "absolute",
            bottom: 0,
            top: 0,
            right: 0,
            left: 0,
          }}
        >
          <ActivityIndicator size={79} color={COLORS.secondary} />
        </View>
      )}

      {showPopup && (
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={handleMuteToggle}>
          <View
            style={{
              justifyContent: "center",
              alignItems: "center",
              display: "flex",
              justifyContent: "center",
              alignItems: "center",
              zIndex: 10,
              position: "absolute",
              bottom: 0,
              top: 0,
              right: 0,
              left: 0,
            }}
          >
            <View style={tw`p-2 bg-black/50 rounded-full`}>
              <Feather
                name={mute ? "volume-x" : "volume-2"}
                size={30}
                color={"white"}
              />
            </View>
          </View>
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
      )}

      <TouchableWithoutFeedback
        onPressIn={handlePressIn}
        onPressOut={handlePressOut}
        onPress={handleMuteToggle}
        onLongPress={handleMuteToggleLong}
      >
        <View
          style={tw`absolute bottom-0 left-0 right-0 top-0 justify-end z-2`}
        >
          {!videoStop && (
            <>
              <View style={tw`py-2 px-4 flex gap-2 items-end`}>
                <View style={tw`flex gap-0 items-center`}>
                  <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleProfile}>
                    {user?.photoURL &&
                    isValidUrl(user?.photoURL) &&
                    !imageFailedToLoad ? (
                      <Image
                        source={{ uri: user?.photoURL }}
                        style={{
                          width: 35,
                          height: 35,
                          resizeMode: "contain",
                          marginBottom: 5,
                          borderRadius: 9999,
                          marginBottom: 8,
                        }}
                        onError={() => setImageFailedToLoad(true)}
                      />
                    ) : (
                      <Avatar.Icon
                        size={36}
                        backgroundColor={COLORS.secondary}
                        icon={"account"}
                      />
                    )}
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
                <View style={tw`flex gap-0 items-center`}>
                  <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => HandleLike(item.id)}>
                    <Image
                      source={
                        isLike
                          ? require("../../../assets/heartfill.png")
                          : require("../../../assets/heart.png")
                      }
                      style={{
                        width: 31,
                        resizeMode: "contain",
                        marginBottom: 5,
                      }}
                    />
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                  <Text style={tw`text-white text-sm font-montserrat`}>
                    {likesCount}
                  </Text>
                </View>
                <View style={tw`flex gap-0 items-center`}>
                  <TouchableOpacity onPress={OpenComments}>
                    <Image
                      source={require("../../../assets/comment.png")}
                      style={{
                        width: 34,
                        resizeMode: "contain",
                        marginBottom: 5,
                      }}
                    />
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                  <Text style={tw`text-white text-sm font-montserrat`}>
                    {item.commentsCount}
                  </Text>
                </View>
                <View style={tw`flex gap-0 items-center`}>
                  <Image
                    source={require("../../../assets/share.png")}
                    style={{
                      width: 34,
                      resizeMode: "contain",
                      marginBottom: 5,
                    }}
                  />
                  <Text style={tw`text-white text-sm font-montserrat`}>
                    Share
                  </Text>
                </View>
              </View>
              <View style={tw`px-4 flex-row justify-start items-center gap-3 `}>
                <Text style={tw`text-white text-lg font-montserrat`}>
                  @{user?.username}
                </Text>
                <TouchableOpacity
                  style={tw`py-1 px-2 rounded-md border border-white flex flex-row items-center gap-1 ${
                    isFollowing ? `bg-transparent text-white` : ""
                  }`}
                  onPress={handleFollow}
                >
                  <Text style={tw`text-white text-base font-montserrat `}>
                    {isFollowing ? "Unfollow" : "Follow"}
                  </Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
              <View style={tw`py-2 px-4`}>
                <FlatList
                  key={index}
                  data={item.hashtags}
                  renderItem={renderItem}
                  keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.key || String(index)}
                  horizontal={true} // Set horizontal to true
                />
              </View>
              <View
                style={tw`flex flex-row items-center gap-2 border-t border-b border-[${COLORS.secondary}] pl-4`}
              >
                <Text
                  style={tw`text-sm text-[${COLORS.secondary}] font-montserrat`}
                >
                  News
                </Text>
                <Text
                  style={tw`text-[10px] text-white flex-1 font-montserrat`}
                  numberOfLines={3}
                >
                  {item.description}
                </Text>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => handleOpen(item.newslink)}>
                  <LinearGradient
                    colors={["#53C8D8", "#668AF7"]}
                    style={tw`py-2`}
                  >
                    <View style={tw`w-8 flex justify-center items-center`}>
                      <Feather
                        name={"chevron-right"}
                        size={30}
                        color={"white"}
                      />
                    </View>
                  </LinearGradient>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
            </>
          )}
          {isCommentModalVisible && (
            <CommentModel
              isVisible={isCommentModalVisible}
              onClose={closeModal}
              post={item}
            />
          )}
        </View>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
      <View style={tw`flex-1 flex py-2 bg-black`}>
        <Video
          ref={video}
          style={styles.container}
          source={{
            uri: item.media[0],
          }}
          useNativeControls={false}
          resizeMode={ResizeMode.COVER}
          shouldPlay={false}
          isLooping
          usePoster
          onLoadStart={handleLoadStart}
          posterSource={{ uri: item.media[1] }}
          posterStyle={{ resizeMode: "cover", height: "100%" }}
          onReadyForDisplay={handleReadyForDisplay}
        />
      </View>
    </>
  );
});

export default PostSingle;


I am not understanding where is the problem in the code.
It maybe due to the absolute styling I am using .
But its a very weird issue.
I have tried the margin and padding adjustments and nothing else.

Note : It only happens when i scroll and it increases with every scroll


My expected output
Overlapping output I am getting as i scroll





you should be able to use scrollToIndex ,since you have the size of each item in the flatlist through getItemLayout, you can scroll to a particular index using
scrollToIndex syntax is as follows
scrollToIndex: (params: {
  index: number;
  animated?: boolean;
  viewOffset?: number;
  viewPosition?: number;
});

you can know more at https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#scrolltoindex
